# I can't fix the <aside> to the same height as article

Tags: css, html

So I'm having trouble trying to fix the aside height to be the same as my article class but I haven't found one that fixes my problem? I've tried setting the right to 0 but that just created a gap between the article tag and aside tag. How can I fix this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px auto;

  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<article>
   <section>
    <header><h2>Om CSS</h2></header>
    
    <p>
    Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin. Lorem  ipsum     har varit standard ända sedan 1500-talet, när en okänd boksättare tog att antal     bokstäver och blandade dem för att göra ett provexemplar av en bok. Lorem ipsum     har inte bara överlevt fem århundraden, utan även övergången till elektronisk       typografi utan större förändringar. Det blev allmänt känt på 1960-talet i           samband med lanseringen av Letraset-ark med avsnitt av Lorem Ipsum, och senare     med mjukvaror som Aldus PageMaker.
    </p>
    
    <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets"> artikel om CSS</a> på Wikipedia
    </p>
        
   </section>
  </article>

<aside>
 <h1>Bildgalleri</h1>
  <img src="images/html5.png " alt="html5">
  <img src="images/css.png"   alt="css3">
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `flexbox`.

Also `padding` does not have `auto` property.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

article {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

aside {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <article>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h2>Om CSS</h2>
      </header>

      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin. Lorem ipsum har varit standard ända sedan 1500-talet, när en okänd boksättare tog att antal bokstäver och blandade dem för att göra ett provexemplar av en bok. Lorem ipsum har inte bara
        överlevt fem århundraden, utan även övergången till elektronisk typografi utan större förändringar. Det blev allmänt känt på 1960-talet i samband med lanseringen av Letraset-ark med avsnitt av Lorem Ipsum, och senare med mjukvaror som Aldus PageMaker.
      </p>

      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets"> artikel om CSS</a> på Wikipedia
      </p>

    </section>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <h1>Bildgalleri</h1>
    <img src="images/html5.png " alt="html5">
    <img src="images/css.png" alt="css3">
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so that worked but it put my header and to the left and my footer to the right :)

Comment: Be sure to wrap the content in a `<div class="flexbox"> </div>` to encapsulate the flexbox effects.

Comment: Oh, should've figured that out myself. Works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CSS `flexbox`

Here is the updated fiddle using `flex`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h2>Om CSS</h2>
      </header>

      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin. Lorem ipsum har varit standard ända sedan 1500-talet, när en okänd boksättare tog att antal bokstäver och blandade dem för att göra ett provexemplar av en bok. Lorem ipsum har inte bara
        överlevt fem århundraden, utan även övergången till elektronisk typografi utan större förändringar. Det blev allmänt känt på 1960-talet i samband med lanseringen av Letraset-ark med avsnitt av Lorem Ipsum, och senare med mjukvaror som Aldus PageMaker.
      </p>

      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets"> artikel om CSS</a> på Wikipedia
      </p>

    </section>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <h1>Bildgalleri</h1>
    <img src="images/html5.png " alt="html5">
    <img src="images/css.png" alt="css3">
  </aside>
</div>
```